# Typo3 Translations in Extbase not working with inline relations

Tags: localization, typo3, translation, relation

i created an extension which uses a main controller which could add inline relations.
I`m using Typo3 11.

If I translate the relations, but not the main Entry, also the language of the already translated relation is the default one.

It doesnt matter, if i set the language to "all", the result is still the same.
I really have to translate the main entry to the other language althought its not necessary.

Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple rule of thumb: Only use language "all" for parent elements that contain only child elements which should be visible in "all" languages too.

As soon as there should be translated children, you should translate the parent element first and usually pick "connected mode", which will give the default language the lead over the target language behaviour.

If there are differences between the number of different child elements and/or there are child elements in a target language, which don't exist in the default language, you should go for "free mode" translations instead.

So actually there is no "although its not necessary" in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the reason why, but if I integrated a "foreach" over my "missingTranslationArray" inline IRRE, at the top of my Template the translation is shown.
It doesnt matter that the foreach doesn't make sense inside my template, but now the missing translations are shown.

```
<f:for each="{myMissingTranslations}" as="myMissingTranslation"></f:for>
```

For me that helps, but i have no answer why its necessary.

Comment: Ok, now I see, that helps only in "normal" views.
If I call the "showAction," its still the same behaviour. The default language is shown instead of the current one.

Its the same Problem as described here: 
https://forge.typo3.org/issues/92768

Answer (score 0):

For all who have the same problem, now I`ve got a solution.

Rewrite the "showAction" inside the controller like:

From:

```
/**
 * action show
* 
 * @param \VENDOR\myExtension\Domain\Model\controller $controller
 * @return void
 */
public function showAction(\VENDOR\myExtension\Domain\Model\controller $controller)
{
```

To:

```
 /**
 * action show
 * 
 * @return void
 */
public function showAction()
{
```

And submit just the "uid". Inside the controller use the "findbyuid" repository for the entry.

```
$id = $this->request->getArguments('entry');
$entry = $this->entryRepository->findByUid($id['entry']); 
$this->view->assign('entries', $entry);
```

The empty repository for each inside the template is also necessary. For that renders every repository inside every single action.

i.e.:

```
<f:for each="{myRelation1}" as="myRelation1"></f:for>
<f:for each="{myRelation2}" as="myRelation2"></f:for>
```